# Make a matrix of 2 rows into a row and a column in R

Tags: r

I'm using R
I have a csv file from single cell data like this, where the column 'cluster' is repeated for all the unique 'gene' column.

```r
dput(markers)
    p_val   avg_logFC   pct.1   pct.2   p_val_adj   cluster gene
APOC1   0   1.696639642 0.939   0.394   0   0   APOC1
APOE    0   1.487160872 0.958   0.475   0   0   APOE
GPNMB   9.30E-269   1.31714457  0.745   0.301   2.49E-264   0   GPNMB
FTL 2.24E-230   0.766844152 1   0.977   6.00E-226   0   FTL
PSAP    2.27E-225   0.98726538  0.925   0.685   6.07E-221   0   PSAP
CTSB    4.84E-211   0.925031015 0.902   0.606   1.29E-206   0   CTSB
CTSS    1.37E-197   0.898457063 0.869   0.609   3.67E-193   0   CTSS
CSTB    8.05E-191   0.853658991 0.918   0.732   2.15E-186   0   CSTB
CTSD    1.23E-187   1.08931251  0.787   0.443   3.30E-183   0   CTSD
IGKC    0   1.560337702 0.998   0.237   0   1   IGKC
IGLC2   0   1.546344857 0.997   0.152   0   1   IGLC2
IGLC3   0   1.342649567 0.967   0.073   0   1   IGLC3
C11orf96    0   1.245172517 0.99    0.253   0   1   C11orf96
COL3A1  0   1.212528128 1   0.343   0   1   COL3A1
LUM 0   1.202452925 0.971   0.143   0   1   LUM
IGHG4   0   0.977399051 0.876   0.092   0   1   IGHG4
HSPG2   0   0.957478533 0.883   0.148   0   1   HSPG2
NNMT    0   0.952577589 0.945   0.213   0   1   NNMT
IGHG1   0   0.913733424 0.861   0.07    0   1   IGHG1
COL6A31 0   1.847828827 0.907   0.192   0   2   COL6A3
PDGFRA  5.38E-292   0.849349193 0.503   0.052   1.44E-287   2   PDGFRA
COL5A21 2.67E-280   1.400314195 0.649   0.105   7.14E-276   2   COL5A2
CALD1   1.11E-275   1.292924443 0.771   0.155   2.98E-271   2   CALD1
CCDC80  1.73E-271   1.168549626 0.706   0.123   4.64E-267   2   CCDC80
COL1A21 1.66E-268   2.004626869 0.966   0.326   4.45E-264   2   COL1A2
DCN1    1.47E-253   1.540631398 0.886   0.254   3.93E-249   2   DCN
COL3A11 3.88E-253   2.216642854 0.955   0.353   1.04E-248   2   COL3A1
FBN1    6.40E-251   0.949521182 0.525   0.07    1.71E-246   2   FBN1
```

I want to transform my matrix so that the row name is the unique cluster name and each column has all the genes from that cluster name (picture 2). How should i write the code?

```r
dput(markers)
0   1   2
APOC1   IGKC    COL6A3
APOE    IGLC2   PDGFRA
GPNMB   IGLC3   COL5A2
FTL C11orf96    CALD1
PSAP    COL3A1  CCDC80
CTSB    LUM COL1A2
CTSS    IGHG4   DCN
CSTB    HSPG2   COL3A1
CTSD    NNMT    FBN1
```

I tried this and the result file has no values.

```r
    markers = read.csv("./markers.csv", row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    z1 = matrix("", ncol = length(unique(markers$cluster)))
    colnames(z1) = unique(markers$cluster)
    for (i in 1:nrow(z1)){
      for (j in 1:ncol(z1)){
        genes1 = as.character(markers$gene)[markers$cluster == rownames(z1)[i]]
        z1[i,0] = paste(genes1, collapse=" ")

    z1 = matrix("", ncol = length(unique(markers$cluster)))
    colnames(z1) = unique(markers$cluster)
    for (i in 1:nrow(z1)){
      for (j in 1:ncol(z1)){
        genes1 = as.character(markers$gene)[markers$cluster == rownames(z1)[i]]
        z1[i,0] = paste(genes1, collapse=" ")
      }
    }
    write.csv(z1, "test.csv")
```

Comment: Please do not use pictures to display data. Make your question reproducible by using ```dput(markers)```

Comment: Sorry. It's my first time posting on here. I fixed the image.

Comment: No you didn't, it is still a picture. Do not post pictures of your data. Use dput(markers) and copy/paste the text into your question.

Comment: I tried that now it's a mess...

Comment: I fixed the formatting using  ``` ```r [code goes here] ``` ```
However, to me the text you posted doesn't really look like the output generated, when one applies `dput()` on a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

This may accomplish what you want, but first we need a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(42)
cluster <- c(rep(0, 8), rep(1, 10), rep(2, 12))
gene <- replicate(30, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 4), collapse=""))
markers <- data.frame(cluster, gene, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This data frame only contains the two columns you are interested in. We need to split the data frame by gene:

```
markers.split <- split(markers$gene, markers$cluster)
```

Print this out. It is a list containing 3 character vectors, one for 0, 1, and 2. The problem with the table format you want is that tables and matrices have to have the same number of rows in each column. We have to pad the vectors so they are all as long as the longest one (12 in this case):

```
rows <- max(sapply(markers.split, length))
markers.sp <- lapply(markers.split, function(x) c(x, rep("", rows - length(x))))
markers.df <- do.call(data.frame, list(markers.sp, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
markers.df
#      X0   X1   X2
# 1  QEAJ ZHDX TIKC
# 2  DRQO VRME PEXN
# 3  XGDE DBXR EVBR
# 4  NTRO CXWQ XQRE
# 5  CIDE URFX NHWY
# 6  METB BTCV UDYG
# 7  HCAJ UBWF JRMU
# 8  XKOV ZJHE VSPZ
# 9       AQGD QLIU
# 10      MJIL KYPH
# 11           WFAM
# 12           NEIW
```

R automatically adds "X" to any column name that starts with a number.